# How can I filter out specific words in a node body?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules

For example, suppose a user creates a node with body value "Hi everyone. GARBAGE VALUE This is my node." Upon submission, I want to be able to filter out "GARBAGE VALUE" and replace it with nothing (or have a replacement value) so that when the node is displayed, it only displays "Hi everyone. This is my node."

Is there any way to do this? Rules? (Rules is the only module that I have yet to figure out despite trying.)

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the Rules module,

- the [Wordfilter](http://drupal.org/project/wordfilter) module allows site
  administrators to filter certain words on all pages.
- the [Phonetic](http://drupal.org/project/phonetic) module goes a step further by including the phonetic characteristics in the comparison as well as a list of profane words.

Comment: Wordfilter does not work. I installed it, set up a word for replacement, and nothing happened. Created a new node with that word, saved it, and the word still showed up. Cleared caches, ran chron. BTW, I'm using Drupal 7.

Edit: Probably because my nodes are all displayed via Views. See [this thread on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/300684).

Answer (score 0):

Both filters worked for me as of date of this posting, except Phonetic word filter did not catch similar words with same sound, different spelling. While they filter words in comments and node titles, they do not filter words in Statuses as a View.
ALSO, from my testing, Wordfilter recognized the base word when used with -ing, -ed, Phonetic did not (you have to enter each specific word). This makes Wordfilter a better choice.